# How should I behave when my undergraduate research marks reduce without any reason in the evaluation process?

Tags: research-undergraduate, evaluation

I'm an undergraduate IT students currently in 4th year. I am doing my individual research these days. My supervisor guides me well and under her supervision I'm doing my research well. But the research evaluation done by a professor and another senior lecturer where they always asked me to do lot of changes to my research. Once I do the changes and present it again, they said that the changes are inappropriate and out of my research scope. I am fed up with this process now. Apparently  they cutoff my marks or reduce the marks in each submission. I have to give my last  research submissions, but with this situation I feel afraid of presenting it. My supervisor doesn't aware of this issue as she is a best friend of that above mentioned senior lecturer. How should I behave in this kind of situation? Any answer would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Talk to your supervisor. Friends or not, she needs to know what the evaluators' criteria are!

Comment: @nengel, Thank you for your advice. But I'm afraid as I have two more submissions to do.

Comment: What are you afraid of?

Comment: @nengel, If my supervisor asks about this from evaluators'  and if they take this issue personally (I just imagine if something happen in that way). That's why I'm afraid of.

Comment: To some extent, evaluation of your research is also evaluation of your supervisor's supervision. Meaning: If she is delighted while others are unhappy with it, there is a problem somewhere that she needs to be made aware of. Best friend or not, they do not seem on the same page about your research and that is hard for you to solve without having input by both of them. (Also, it is not any better for their friendship if the "You brought my student down!" issue arises when it is too late to do anything about it.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the first things I tell my graduate students is:

> Let me know when there's a problem, **not a crisis.**

If you talk to your advisor now and let her know about the developing situation, she might be able to intervene and help you before the end of the process.

If you do nothing, and just hope for the best, you may find yourself in a situation where your advisor can't really help. (For example, if you are *officially* assigned a bad grade, it may be too late for her to do anything.